# plsql error using xmlattributes with clob

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, clob

I have this query. It works fine only if the column `my_table_column_string_xml` is set to `VARCHAR2`.

Unfortunatly, this column must contains longer data then `varchar2` max length.

I tryed to move the column to clob.. but if I run the query I obtain the error:

> ORA-19202: Error during XML Elaboration 
>   ORA-00932: incoerent data types: awaited  -, obtained CLOB
>   ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 237
>   ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 271
>   ORA-06512: a line 1

I also tryed to set the column to `XMLTYPE` but I receive the same error message when I run my query (apart the fat it SAYS obtained CLOB)

```
select xmlelement("ROOT",xmlagg(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy
           ('select level,xmlelement(evalname entita,xmlattributes(my_table_column_string_xml as MyXmlString)) 
              from( select *
                    from MyTable t                  
                  )
              connect by prior my_table_column_object = my_table_column_object_father
              start with my_table_column_object_father is null
              order by my_table_column_order
           ')))).getClobVal()  as xml 
        from dual;
```

I need to have the same result of my original query even if I use a clob column